# smoothdivscroll logo parade dont start

Tags: javascript, carousel

I just add a logo parade to the top of this website. After having sort out all the errors, and review all the code, the parade dont start.... i cannot find what it's like that

http://acecrodeo.com/01-acec.php?lang=fra

even if i have a doc type, the "view source" show another doctype :

i dont think this is the problem, but that another problem...

now i like the logo parade to work, please
i use the jquery : smoothdivscroll

Comment: i guess my firebug is dead... because NO errors... no warning...

Comment: i got this error : The character encoding declaration of the HTML document was not found when prescanning the first 1024 bytes of the file. When viewed in a differently-configured browser, this page will reload automatically. The encoding declaration needs to be moved to be within the first 1024 bytes of the file.

Comment: OK, i restart, reinstall firebug, and NOW, the loading, errors, and warning is gone, all the required .JS is loaded, but no scrooling.... why..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, getting to the source code of the demo in the site and copy/pasting this css make it work.. thanks you

```
div.scrollWrapper {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
div.scrollableArea {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: it worked with just 
`div.scrollWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}`
 in my site but thanks for idea

Answer (score 1):

Did you open up the debugger

```
TypeError: $.widget is not a function
http://acecrodeo.com/js/jquery.smoothDivScroll-1.2.js
Line 1045
```

and

```
ReferenceError: FALSE is not defined
http://acecrodeo.com/01-acec.php?lang=fra
Line 87
```

Clicking on the error takes you to the code

```
$("#logoParade").smoothDivScroll({

    hotSpotScrolling: FALSE,  //<-- JavaScript is case sensitive needs to be false!
    autoScrollingMode: "always",
    autoScrollingDirection: "endlessloopright",
    autoScrollingStep: 1,
    autoScrollingInterval: 25

});
```

Comment: Fix most of he problem, the The character encoding declaration of the HTML document .. is still there, but is a warning !

Comment: That is just the browser telling you to move the encoding to the correct location. Not breaking anything or related to the bug you had.